# Iterate over elements in div using AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a list of dictionaries in the following format:

```
[{
    "product_id": 1,
    "product_name": "Formal Shoes",
    "product_price": 220,
    "img_path": "images/tp1.jpg"
}, {
    "product_id": 2,
    "product_name": "Formal Shirt",
    "product_price": 190,
    "img_path": "images/tp2.jpg"
}, {
    "product_id": 3,
    "product_name": "Blazer",
    "product_price": 160,
    "img_path": "images/tp3.jpg"
}, {
    "product_id": 4,
    "product_name": "Casual Shoes",
    "product_price": 250,
    "img_path": "images/tp4.jpg"
}, {
    "product_id": 5,
    "product_name": "Inner Wear",
    "product_price": 50,
    "img_path": "images/ip2.jpg"
}, {
    "product_id": 6,
    "product_name": "Shoes",
    "product_price": 150,
    "img_path": "images/shp8.jpg"
}, {
    "product_id": 7,
    "product_name": "Formal Shirt",
    "product_price": 100,
    "img_path": "images/cap1.jpg"
}, {
    "product_id": 8,
    "product_name": "Watch",
    "product_price": 200,
    "img_path": "images/wap3.jpg"
}]
```

I am getting products from an api call. And I am trying to render it in my html using the following code:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="product in products">
```

But this throws an error:

```
angular.js:10061 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=product%20in%20products&p1=string%3Ad
    at angular.js:36
    at angular.js:20508
    at Object.fn (angular.js:12385)
    at k.$digest (angular.js:12512)
    at k.$apply (angular.js:12777)
    at h (angular.js:8371)
    at v (angular.js:8585)
    at XMLHttpRequest.w.onreadystatechange (angular.js:8524)
```

Is there any other way to do this?

I tried the following approaches but it didn't work:
1. Iterating over numbers i and using i as an index to access products
2. Using track by $index

```
<script>
      var app = angular.module('prodModule', []);
      app.controller('prodCntlr', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.getProducts = function () {
          $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url : url
          }).then(function (response) {
            var prds = JSON.parse(response.data.Payload)
            console.log(prds['Payload']);
            $scope.products = prds['Payload'];
          }).catch(function (error) {
              console.log("error!")
          });
        };
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$scope.products` is exactly as you've shown it above? `track by $index` should work if that is the case, so I suspect there may be an issue there. Can you add the code that fetches this from the API? (controller and/or service)

Comment: Your code works without any problems. Which version of AngularJS are you using? Can you provide more controller and view code?

Comment: @AJFunk: Yeah, I did console.log and then I copied it here. I have added the code which fetches products

Comment: @Hoa: 1.2.23 is the version. I have added the code.

Comment: @blackmamba The problem is with the view. Add your view code, please. Much better if you can create a Plunker which reproduces the problem.